# On C++ global operator new: why it can be replaced

Tags: c++

I wrote a small program in VS2005 to test whether C++ global operator new can be overloaded. It can.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "iomanip"
#include "string"
#include "new"

using namespace std;

class C {
    public:
        C() { cout<<"CTOR"<<endl; }
};

void * operator new(size_t size) 
{
    cout<<"my overload of global plain old new"<<endl;
    // try to allocate size bytes
    void *p = malloc(size);
    return (p);
}

int main() {
    C* pc1 = new C;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above, my definition of operator new is called. If I remove that function from the code, then operator new in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\crt\src\new.cpp gets called.

All is good. However, in my opinion, my implementations of operator new does NOT overload the new in new.cpp, it CONFLICTS with it and violates the one-definition rule. Why doesn't the compiler complain about it? Or does the standard say since operator new is so special, one-definition rule does not apply here?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should always implement a matching `operator delete` for every `operator new` you implement. (I know this was just to show your point, but I just can't get myself to let it stand without this warning.)

Comment: Perhaps should you edit the title of the question, I thought you wanted to know the various uses for replacing it when in fact you wanted to know why replacing it did not provoked an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, global `operator new` is special in that programs may provide a replacement implementation for it.

Replaceable forms are the single object and array forms of `operator new` and `operator delete` and the "no throw" variants. Other forms, such as placement new are not replaceable.